# I have 4 Winlogons running in my computer

Tags: windows-8, keylogger, winlogon.exe

i usually only have 1 running
i been searching on internet and some people say when you have over one winlogon.exe you are being keylogged

im actually being keylogged or im just overreacting?

im using a windows 8

Comment: Your unlikely being key logged random people are not compromised in this way.  What are the users called?

Comment: post screenshots of ProcessExplorer which shows the full commandline of all Winlogons.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a solution here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/multiple-winlogonexe-processes-running/2fbb5d54-734e-406e-943e-60f207dd4eae

The answer describes that it may be a virus/keylogger and also provides an online scan tool from Microsoft for free. I would also recommend checking your scheduled tasks on startup, and see if you're running any programs as another user on login.